# push array object into localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

```
var arr = [];
var obj = {};

obj.order_id = 1;
obj.name = "Cake";
obj.price = "1 Dollar";
obj.qty = 1;

arr.push(obj);

localStorage.setItem('buy',JSON.stringify(arr));
```

The problem with above code is when executing it will replace the existing array object, how to add new obj into the array if the order_id is not the same?

Comment: What code are you running to have it replace the existing array object?  push should never overwrite, and when I run the example you gave I don't see it overwriting.

Comment: `Array.prototype.push` modifies the given array. Are you looking to create a new array with with pushed object?

Comment: The code above does not reproduce the problem

Comment: Use a loop to test the values already in the array. Or use the [`.some()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to first retrieve whatever is *already* in local storage (if anything), parse that back to an array and add an item to it if the id isn't already present, then put the result back into local storage?

Comment: @nnnnnn Most probably that's the case.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes and also do alter the qty (quantity) if the inserted order_id is found.

Comment: OK. That's fairly clear. I suggest you again [edit] your question to say that (rather than relying on clarifications in comments). And make the code sample a bit more consistent: currently you have an `arr` variable that starts as an empty array, and a `toCart_json_arr` variable that isn't initialised at all in the code shown - should they be the same variable?

Answer (score -1):

**New Answer:**

```
var arr = [];
var obj = {};

obj.order_id = 1;
obj.name = "Cake";
obj.price = "1 Dollar";
obj.qty = 1;

$change = 'no'; for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){ if(obj.order_id == arr[i].order_id){ obj.qty = obj.qty + arr[i].qty; arr[i] = obj; $change ='yes'; } }
if($change == 'no'){ arr.push(obj); }

console.log(arr);
```

And for saving it in localstorage see my answer here: [push multiple array object into localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353101/push-multiple-array-object-into-localhost/31353183#31353183)

**Old Answer:**
The best solution would be to make 'arr' an object with the order_id being the key of the object. You get something like this:

```
var arr = {};
var obj = {};

obj.order_id = 1;
obj.name = "Cake";
obj.price = "1 Dollar";
obj.qty = 1;

arr[obj.order_id]= obj;
console.log(arr);
```

This will only replace the order if the order_id is the same. If you really want and array, you have to make a function that goes through the array and checks every order_id.