# push multiple array object into localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

```
(function{
    var array = localStorage.getItem('id') || [];
    obj = {};
    obj.id = 1;
    array.push(obj);

    localStorage.setItem('id', JSON.stringify(array));
}();
```

why in my localStorage it doesn't insert the obj twice? I'm seeing it replace the existing one.

Comment: Your code results in a syntax error.  It does not run as you've posted it.  Plus, you're attempting to write the same one item array into localStorage each time so it would be no surprise that the contents is always a one item array.

Comment: Is this the same problem as [another user's question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31352976/push-array-object-into-localstorage#comment50688677_31352976) from half an hour ago? Your code creates a new, *empty* array, adds one item to it, and then puts a stringified version into local storage. Why would it *not* replace whatever was already in local storage? You need to retrieve what was there and add to it, not create an empty array (except the first time).

Comment: @nnnnnn can you show me? sorry new to javascript.

Comment: in localstorage if you want to add value each has to unique. each key represent as primary key or index for saving and retriving value.

Answer (score 0):

It does replace the existing one.

Try this:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('id')){  array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('id')) } else {
var array = []; }
obj = {};
obj.id=1;
array.push(obj);

localStorage.setItem('id',JSON.stringify(array));
```

Everytime you are adding it first gets the localstorage item and then adds to it and puts it back.

Comment: this worked! thanks. Any idea how to avoid duplication? increment id by 1 if the same id found, any idea?

Comment: There are two options for that one, you change the array into an object, and then the id will be the key. (array = {}; obj = {}; obj.id = 1; array[obj.id] = obj;) What happens if the id is same it replaces the old one, if the id is different it is added. The other is to go throught the array and check for if it exists.